# Four Square API for updated venue

Tags: java, foursquare

I looked into FourSquare to check if there are any API's avaialable to get the list of venues that have been updated for a specific time period.

But could not find any, Given a time frame, is it possible to get the list of venues updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dean for your response. You have a sitemap which has the list of site map id's.

(1) Sometimes I see that the sitemap id and the venue id are difference. Why is that so?
(2) How frequently does your sitemap xml gets updated? I think thats the only way for me to see if there are new venues added in case I need to cache it for 30 days rather than hitting the APi everytime.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no API endpoint available to do this as far as I am aware.

Venues can be updated in various ways. Tips and images are often added. For highly popular places, this could be daily.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the populate places at least?

Comment: Im tempted to say no because the definition of popular is dependent on context. Your best bet for your questions are is to get at foursquare directly. I believe the email is api@foursquare.com ..but don't be surprised if they tell you something similar to what I've said. Do however share if they gave you a solution.

Comment: The sitemap xml gets updated daily. As you said they do not have any other API call for getting popular places

Comment: Just wanted to share the the responses provided by foursquare support.(1) Right now I am using the sitemap xml to cache my data temporarily. Using the sitemap id when I invoke the venue API to get the details, the response indicated that it is deleted. So I had a question to them asking if a venue is deleted, will the id be reused. The response I got was that a venue id that is deleted will not be reused.

Comment: (2) The sitemap xml actually has the venue id. When we invoke the API, the response has a different venue id. The reason for this is, sometimes venues are merged together. They have built the API so that the end user does not feel the glitch.